# jQuery grid-system - handing different row widths

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function in jQuery for my home-made grid system. When a `row` has too many `column`s in it, it removes the HTML code from that `row`.

Normally in my grid system it fits 12 columns in 1 row, but with the function this can easily be changed.

One column with the size of *1* (declared as: `column size-1`) has a width of 1/12 (or 8.3333%).

```
function validateRowWidth() {
    var _row = $('.row');
    _row.each(function (index, element) {
        var totalWidth = 0,
            _columnSize = $(element).find('[class*="size-"]');
        _columnSize.each(function (index, element) {
            var width = $(element).outerWidth(true),
                inProcent = Math.round((width / $(element).parent().width()) * 100);
            totalWidth += inProcent;
        });
        if (totalWidth > 100) {
            console.log('You have to many columns into your '+(index + 1)+'th row');
            $(element).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any way I can improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I pondered:

- What's with the underscores everywhere?
- Why not use regular jQuery convention and use `this` instead of `element` in your `each` iterator?
- What's the use-case for this? A regular user will never see the console, so logging to it doesn't help anyone.
- Even if someone is watching the console, what's the point of warning them when the row is just summarily removed? At least give the user a chance to fix the problem. It's worse if you're not looking at the console - then stuff is just *gone* with no explanation.
- And the warning, "You have too many columns", isn't really truthful. The problem is that the columns - even if it's just 1 - are *too wide*. You code isn't checking how many there are.
- But mostly: Why use percentages? Just compare widths directly. Saves you a whole lot of trouble (and code)

This seems clearer to me:

```
function validateRowWidth() {
  $('.row').each(function (index) {
    var row = $(this), // use `this`
        widthSum = 0;

    // sum up the (direct descendant) column widths
    row.children('[class*="size-"]').each(function () {
      widthSum += $(this).outerWidth(true); // 1 line is all you need here
    });

    // compare and warn if need be
    if(widthSum > row.width()) {
      // alert is not a great choice, but it's better than console.log,
      // if this is user-facing. Explain the problem, and propose solutions.
      alert("Row " + index + " is too wide. Remove one or more columns or make them narrower.");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time :). And yeah, i dont know either, it made the code more clear for me. And some guy told me that the `element` argument was more precise then `$(this)`. Yeah and that grammatica wasnt my strongest point either. Doing this with `width`s is going alot better indeed, but i had to call `Math.floor` on the `widthSum +=` to make it actually work.

Comment: @Dreiba No prob. Wait and see if there are a other answers, otherwise hit the checkmark. As for `element` being more precise, that's just nonsense. Sure, `this` changes value based on context, so `this` in the outer function is not the same as `this` in the inner functions. But that's what we want. And the same thing value-changing thing happened it your code anyway, because you called the argument `element` in both the inner and outer function, so the latter shadowed the former.