# Checking number of of columns in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a own made grid system and made a jQuery function for that to check if there are not too many `column`s in each `row`. If so, delete the HTML code of the row.

Normally in my grid system, there fits 12 columns in 1 row, but I can change that.

In HTML, I've written them like this:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
            </div>
```

In this jQuery function, im checking the number of each `[class*="size-"]` and counting them up.

```
    function validateRowWidths() {
        $('.row').each(function (index) {
            var row = $(this),
                columns = 0;
            row.children('[class*="size-"]').each(function () {
                var eachSizeNumber = Number($(this).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0]);
                columns += eachSizeNumber;
            });

            row.children('[class*="offset-"]').each(function () {
                var eachSizeNumber = Number($(this).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0]);
                columns += eachSizeNumber;
            });

            row.children('[class*="push-"]').each(function () {
                var eachSizeNumber = Number($(this).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0]);
                columns += eachSizeNumber;
            });

            row.children('[class*="pull-"]').each(function () {
                var eachSizeNumber = Number($(this).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0]);
                columns += eachSizeNumber;
            });

            console.log(columns);

            if (columns > 12) {
                $(this).remove();
                console.log("Row " + (index + 1) + " is has to many colums in it. Remove one or more columns or make them narrower.");
            }
        });
    }
```

For all the grid extensions such as `offset`, `push` or `pull` i have to write that same `each` function again.

The HTML markup for the grid extensions looks like this:

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column size-1 offset-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1 push-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
                <div class="column size-1">...</div>
            </div>
```

Can I do this in a better way?

Comment: To be honest, this shouldn't be done with jQuery. This shouldn't be done at all in the first place. this smells of an XY problem, try defining what you are really trying to do

Comment: @Pinoniq This is what i'm trying to do. But why shouldnt it be done then?

Comment: You are using client-side powered scripts to remove a div that shouldn't be there in the first place. You should have your view output correct HTML. You are writing a client-side fix for a server-side problem (the html returned could be incorrect). Hence, XY problem

Comment: @Pinoniq Indeed, but if you place that 13th column, it starts to look very ugly. And the 'user' may not know how it comes right?

Comment: don't place that 13th column then ;)

Comment: @Pinoniq Yeah, i know :P That's what i'm preventing right now? Or am i seeing that wrong?

Comment: You are not really preventing it, you are removing the entire row if the problem occurs. That is harsh, what if someone wants it to look ugly? Simply don't add to many columns, problem solved.

Comment: @Pinoniq But, a developer doesnt want to make the users site look ugly right? Or atleast, not the way it supposed to be.

Comment: If it is possible to add to many columns to a row, fix that bug first. If it doesn't look good, fix the css. Don't write some code that simply removes all visible traces of the bug. We are developers and not some censoring tyran ;)

Comment: @Pinoniq But one row, is equal to the width of your screen i supose. So you cant have 1 row, wich has 2 rows. Right? And do you mean fix it by hiding the overflow or?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15176/discussion-between-bas-and-pinoniq).

Comment: Why not? ofcourse you can. this is not a table, it's simply a containing div, with other divs inside that float next to each other. Once all the divs take up the entire width, the next one is simply placed on the 'next row'. I think your real problem here is that you don't understand what float:left does to your dom elements =:)

Comment: @Pinoniq So you mean that one `row` div, can actually contain more 'rows' of columns?

Comment: yup :-) cool huh :)

Comment: @Pinoniq Yeah, but i have no idea how to change that CSS then... :(

Comment: look into grids like susy: http://susy.oddbird.net/ and foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery check row size function](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54249/jquery-check-row-size-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

1. Using [Multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)
2. Moving the calculation logic to a function so that you can re-use it elsewhere or refactor/change in a single place if the need be.

Applying this you get something like the following:

```
row.children('[class*="size-"],[class*="offset-"],[class*="push-"],[class*="pull-"]').each(function () {
            columns += getCurrentSize(this);
        });

 function getCurrentSize(element){
     return Number($(element).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0]);
 }
```

However, if you want each class to be evaluated separately, as mentioned in the comments, you could first try adding these elements to an array and then perform a common action on them. Something like -

```
var uniqueClassColumns = [];
uniqueClassColumns.push($('[class*="size-"]'));
uniqueClassColumns.push($('[class*="offset-"]'));
uniqueClassColumns.push($('[class*="push-"]'));
uniqueClassColumns.push($('[class*="pull-"]'));

uniqueClassColumns.each(function () {
                columns += getCurrentSize(this);
            });

     function getCurrentSize(element){
         return Number($(element).attr('class').match(/\d+$/)[0]);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks.
I'll add the explanation. In the meanwhile - whats a SO-like answer? Din't get you.

Comment: @Vandesh here on CR we don't usually see things as problems. your answer treats the posted code as a problem and you provide a "fix". That's the SO-way of answering. here on CR it's more like we provide "guidance" on how to write cleaner, **better** code. That is easily understandable. We take the code that was posted, and examine it, explain what we would do different and then maybe post a different code-sample.

Comment: @Vandesh again welcome ;) Feel free to visit us in [chat] if you have questions. Also skimming throug other answers and [meta] might help you understand better what I meant ;)

Comment: Yup. Just stuck in the StackOverflow habit ;) Thanks again.

Comment: @Vandesh Thanks for this :) its much compacter, but there's one small problem. It only works for `[class*="size-"]`.

Comment: I think I understood what your problem might be. Check out this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9TcuK/1/  
It alerts the value 2 because it only has two jquery elements as the result of the multiple selector. It doesn't count the first div twice, but only once. Similar is your problem I think. Will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Vandesh Sorry, i dont understand what your saying atm.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. It should make things clear.

Comment: @Vandesh Thanks :) But cant you have the array preloaded? so that all those are already in there?

Comment: What do you mean by pre-loaded?

Comment: @Vandesh that the values are already in the array?